# Getting Error as org.springframework.web.servlet.PageNotFound handleHttpRequestMethodNotSupported

Tags: java, spring-mvc, spring-security

I have followed the link [Example Link](http://o7planning.org/web/fe/default/en/document/29799/simple-login-web-application-using-spring-mvc-spring-security-and-spring-jdbc)  to create the Login Application. I have not used maven for the project.

When iam running the application http://localhost:9889/SpringMVCDemo/login

getting redirected to below link

http://localhost:9889/SpringMVCDemo/j_spring_security_check

iam getting the following error.

in the console iam getting below error message

```
INFO: Server startup in 18487 ms
Aug 10, 2015 4:07:54 PM org.springframework.web.servlet.PageNotFound handleHttpRequestMethodNotSupported
WARNING: Request method 'POST' not supported
```

In Browser

```
HTTP Status 405 - Request method 'POST' not supported
type Status report

message Request method 'POST' not supported

description The specified HTTP method is not allowed for the requested resource.
```

---

Apache Tomcat/8.0.24

**EDIT:**
Login.jsp

```
<html>
<head><title>Login</title></head>
<body>
 <h1>Login</h1>
 <form name='f' action="j_spring_security_check" method='POST' >
    <table>
       <tr>
          <td>User:</td>
          <td><input type='text' name='username' value=''></td>
       </tr>
       <tr>
          <td>Password:</td>
          <td><input type='password' name='password' /></td>
       </tr>
       <tr>
          <td><input name="submit" type="submit" value="submit" /></td>
       </tr>
    </table>
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

Spring-Security

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans:beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/security"
xmlns:beans="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans" 
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
http://www.springframework.org/schema/security
http://www.springframework.org/schema/security/spring-security.xsd">


   <http use-expressions="true">
       <intercept-url pattern="/" access="isAnonymous()" />
       <intercept-url pattern="/welcome" access="isAnonymous()" />
       <intercept-url pattern="/login" access="isAnonymous()" />
       <intercept-url pattern="/logout" access="isAnonymous()" />


       <intercept-url pattern="/userInfo"
           access="hasAnyRole('ROLE_USER', 'ROLE_ADMIN')" />
       <intercept-url pattern="/admin" access="hasRole('ROLE_ADMIN')" />
       <intercept-url pattern="/other/**" access="isAuthenticated()" />

       <access-denied-handler error-page="/403" />

       <form-login login-page='/login' login-processing-url="/j_spring_security_check"
           default-target-url="/userInfo" always-use-default-target="false"
           authentication-failure-url="/login?error=true" username-parameter="username"
           password-parameter="password" />

       <logout logout-url="/logout" logout-success-url="/logoutSuccessful"
           delete-cookies="JSESSIONID" invalidate-session="true" />

   </http>

   <authentication-manager>
       <authentication-provider>
           <user-service>
               <user name="user1" password="12345" authorities="ROLE_USER" />
               <user name="admin1" password="12345" authorities="ROLE_USER, ROLE_ADMIN" />
           </user-service>
       </authentication-provider>



       <!-- authentication from database -->
       <authentication-provider>
           <jdbc-user-service data-source-ref="myDataSource"
               users-by-username-query="select username,password, enabled from users where username=?"
               authorities-by-username-query="select username, role from users where username=?" />
       </authentication-provider>

   </authentication-manager>

</beans:beans>
```

I have read some answers in stack overflow but dint find the solution.

Can some one please help me.

Comment: the error message says, that you can only send a "GET" request to `j_spring_security_check`. So what is actually the question? How do you make `j_spring_security_check` accepting 'POST' or how do you send a 'GET' there?

Comment: my doubt is what change we need to do so that it will work. ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to @JohnnyAW Suggesting to do more R&D on net by doing that i found the answer we need to implement the CSRF Token in the login page.

when i have added the above lines in login page it worked properly.

Answer (score 0):

the easiest way would be, to change the request Method to 'GET' in the login-Form. In `loginPage.jsp` change the form like this:

```
<form name='f' action="j_spring_security_check" method='GET'>
```

EDIT: actually you don't want to send the login-request as a 'GET'-request, since you would be able to see the credentials in your log-files. It's ok for testing purposes, but at some point you will want to change the request to 'POST'

Comment: yes earlier i have tried that thing changing from POST to get, but stiil the error                                  Aug 10, 2015 4:52:49 PM org.springframework.web.servlet.PageNotFound noHandlerFound
WARNING: No mapping found for HTTP request with URI [/SpringMVCDemo/j_spring_security_check] in DispatcherServlet with name 'mvc-dispatcher'                    I don't want to change from POST to GET as the credentials will be visible in the browser.

Comment: still 405? whats with 'PUT'?

Comment: HTTP Status 404 - 
type Status report

message 
description The requested resource is not available.


--------------------------------------------------------------------------------

Comment: Wait, do you get 404 for 'GET'? Btw. you don't see credentials in the browser, only in the access-log on your server. Post your login.jsp and spring-security.xml

Comment: When i use GET i can see the credentials in the browser. and get 404 Error.

Comment: you can see it, because you get 404, you wouldn't see it without the error, because you would be redirected to some url after login. Your setup seems to be ok. Ill try the code later today, maybe ill find the problem

Answer (score 0):

I ran into a similar issue while integrating an angular app with Spring. Thought of sharing the fix as an answer here to help future readers.

As per the [post here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43096324/4036921), I had enabled Basic Authentication in Spring Security and trying to issue a login request from the angular app.

```
http.post(this.loginUrl, {}, options);
```

Since Basic Authentication doesn't accept POST method, got below error,

```
Aug 30, 2017 5:47:30 PM org.springframework.web.servlet.PageNotFound handleHttpRequestMethodNotSupported
WARNING: Request method 'POST' not supported
```

To fix this issue, I just changed the service call in the angular app as below and it worked.

```
http.request(this.loginUrl, options);
```

Answer (score 0):

Use CSRF token in action -

```
<form name='f' action="j_spring_security_check?${_csrf.parameterName}=${_csrf.token}" method='POST' >
```

Hope this will work.