# angular 2 login with spring security

Tags: rest, angular, spring-mvc, spring-security, restful-authentication

im trying to integrate spring security with a custom angular 2 login, that is a specific endpoint of my app is protected with spring security, trying to access it will redirect to /login that is handled in angular 2. as things stands now i have no clue as to how to perform the login and grant access to the backend API once logged.

i am configuring spring security as follows:

```
@Override
protected void configure(final HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
    http
        .csrf().disable()
        .cors().and()
        .authorizeRequests()
        .antMatchers("/api/someEndpoint/**")
        .hasRole(ADMIN_ROLE).and().formLogin()
        .loginPage("/login").and().logout();
}


@Override
protected void configure(final AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
    auth.userDetailsService(userDetailsService).passwordEncoder(passwordEncoder);
}
```

as I had the default login everything worked fine, but I have found myself unable to create a working angular 2 login integration.
I tried the following code in angular 2 to no avail:

```
login(loginDetails:Object) {
    console.log(loginDetails)
    const headers = new Headers({ 'Content-Type': 'application/json' });
const options = new RequestOptions({ headers: headers });
const body = JSON.stringify(loginDetails);
    console.log(headers);
    console.log(body);
return this.http.post(this.loginUrl, body, options) 
}
```

as far as I know spring security defaults for username and password variable names are "username" and "password", which i am sure are being passed in the request body so when passing some invalid user data like `{"username":"admin", "password" : "pass"}`I should be redirected to /login?error or something, and when successfully authenticated I should be redirected to /welcome and stay authenticated

I have the user and pass defined in my db and my custom userDetailsService checks against it
 any answers, comments or questions are welcome

Comment: `formLogin` expects the parameters of content type `application/x-www-form-urlencoded` and not `application/json` ones. Since you're working with the API, you've to use either HTTP Basic or OAuth2

Comment: isn't the way i'm trying to do it right now HTTP basic?

Comment: actually you aren't

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Once you're working with an API you've to use the HTTP Basic authentication.
It's also required to use HTTPS to prevent the main-in-middle attack.

To implement HTTP Basic with Angular the login service would look like this:

```
login (loginDetails: any): Observable<LoginResponse> { // custom class, may be empty for now

    let headers = new Headers({ 
      'Authorization': 'Basic ' + btoa(loginDetails.login + ':' + loginDetails.pass),
      'X-Requested-With': 'XMLHttpRequest' // to suppress 401 browser popup
    });

    let options = new RequestOptions({ 
      headers: headers 
    });

    return this.http.post(this.loginUrl, {}, options)
      .catch(e => this.handleError(e)); // handle 401 error - bad credentials
}
```

... then you subscribe this in the caller component:

```
loginNow() {
   this
     .loginService
     .login(this.loginDetails)
     .subscribe(next => {
        this.router.navigateByUrl("/"); // login succeed
     }, error => {
        this.error = "Bad credentials"; // or extract smth from <error> object
     });
}
```

Then you can use the `loginNow()` method inside component templates like `(click)="loginNow()`.

As soon as the server will accept an authorization, `JSESSIONID` will be stored in your browser automatically because of Spring Security features and you won't be forced to send the credentials each time you access private resources.

Your login server method may look like this:

```
@PreAuthorize("hasRole('USER')")
@PostMapping("/login")
public ResponseEntity login() {
    return new ResponseEntity<>(HttpStatus.OK);
}
```

... it would reject with `401 UNAUTHORIZED` when the authorization fails or accept with `200 SUCCESS` when it's not.

How to setup a server in the proper way there's a number of Spring Security demo projects present: https://github.com/spring-guides/tut-spring-security-and-angular-js

Comment: thanks for your answer, i have one question thou: (whops, edit:)
{"username":"admin", "password" : "pass"} this is the string that i am sending, i dont have the admin and pass separated, i get them from a formGroup.value.

how would this line: 'Authorization': 'Basic ' + btoa(loginDetails.login + ':' + loginDetails.pass) 

be modified?

Comment: the best option there is to refuse from `formGroup` and to use two-way binding with the component fields like this: `[(ngModel)]="this.username"` by it's specifying on `input` elements. Otherwise, you've to parse them out anyway, possibly, by like this -> `JSON.parse(this.loginDetails).username` etc

Comment: well i bound the username and pass to the component and passed them to the login service, but it always redirects to the welcome page even if bad credentials are typed, also i am not being authenticated as when i type correct credentials i am redirected to welcome but cant acces the secured endpoint

Comment: please ignore my last comment (i wont delete it as it may be useful to somebody), i forgot to enable httpbasic in the spring security config

Answer (score 0):

Your spring security config needs to look like this

```
 http!!
     .cors().and()
     .csrf().disable()
    .authorizeRequests()
     .requestMatchers(object: RequestMatcher {
       override fun matches(request: HttpServletRequest?): Boolean {
         return CorsUtils.isCorsRequest(request)
       }
     }).permitAll()
    .antMatchers("/api/**").authenticated()
    .anyRequest().permitAll()
    .and()
    .formLogin().permitAll()
```

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue, but I had to override the successlogout handler as mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58074100/1927543).